# IE weird characters showing on clicking back button

Tags: character-encoding, internet-explorer-8, internationalization

Currently I am working on a i18n project where users can switch languages.

Character encoding is utf-8

The problem happens only in IE8 when:

- currently user is in a **https** page.
- Going to a **http** page after any action - like clicking a static page link
- Now clicking back button from the current (**http**) page
- Weird characters showing up instead of original czech characters.

Working perfectly in all other browsers like chrome, firefox etc.

Anyone has faced this kind of issue ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the character encoding in the page where you are seeing this problem is defined correctly?

How this should be done is described on [this W3C page](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations).

Comment: Aneesh and I checked that. It's a bug in Internet Explorer. You can see the same problem on several sites.

Answer (score -1):

Abandon Internet Explorer 8 support?

Comment: This isn't a suitable answer and is not a solution

Comment: It is a potential solution.